# Excel duplicates the changes from one sheet to all sheets in xls

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have an xls file with 5 sheets in it. If I write ="something" in B2 in sheet1 all sheets 2-5 also is changed in B2.

This happened after several problems with 2003 vs. 2007 versions of office. Now we all have the 2007 office, but the problem persists.

Does any one know some weird setting that would do that?

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you have all the sheets selected before you type in the cell. For example, if I want my name on every sheet in a workbook, I can select all the sheets, then type my name in a cell and hit Enter. The name will appear in that cell on every sheet. The same would be true of the formula you're typing.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that all cells in sheets 2-5 have a formula with a reference to the equivalent cell on the 1st sheet?

For example, your cell B2 on sheet 2 would contain the formula `=Sheet1!B2`.

Comment: If i dont write anything in sheet1 other data exist in all the other sheets

Comment: Do you have a macro running in the workbook that would do this?

Comment: Ill see if I can find one...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is simple, just right click on the sheet tab and select "Ungroup".